# How to write cssSelector to Find Save Button

Tags: css, webdriver

please help me to write css Selector to identify Save Button.
WebElement save_btn = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(""));

```
<div id="button-1050" class="x-btn actionButton x-box-item x-toolbar-item x-btn-default-toolbar-small x-noicon x-btn-noicon x-btn-default-toolbar-small-noicon" style="border-width: 1px; left: 293px; top: 5px; margin: 0px;">
<em id="button-1050-btnWrap">
<button id="button-1050-btnEl" autocomplete="off" role="button" hidefocus="true" type="button" style="height: 16px;" class="x-btn-center">
<span id="button-1050-btnInnerEl" class="x-btn-inner" style="">Save</span>
<span id="button-1050-btnIconEl" class="x-btn-icon "></span>
```

Comment: Have you tried WebElement save_btn = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#button-1050-btnEl"));

Comment: yes, the problem is that this ID is dynamically generated and there is no sense to use it.

Comment: You can try something like this: save_btn = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[id$='btnEl']")); Where btnEl is the part that is not dynamically generated.

Comment: yes, it works, but the problem is that "Cancel" button has the same part in ID too. So it hits the button, but I don't know which. Is there any chance to specify object by "Save" word?

Comment: I don't believe there is a way for CSS to do what you want.  XPath can use .contains() to find an element.  For example, some XPath I found elsewhere:  save_btn = driver.findElement(By.xpathSelector("//*[text()[contains(.,'Save')]]"));  I know that's not what you were asking for.  My other suggestion is to post more of the HTML, or review it to see if there's a name or id above the Save button you can use as a starting point for a CSS selector.

Comment: @Richard, thank you so much - it works with save_btn = driver.findElement(By.xpathSelector("//*[text()[contains(.,'Save')]]"));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My official answer is:

```
save_btn = driver.findElement(By.xpathSelector("//*[text()[contains(.,'Save')]]"));
```